# Caching data fetched from API - php

Tags: php, caching, scheduled-tasks

I am using an API to fetch certain data but due to its large amount, I can not fetch it each time the user accesses the website. Instead I thought of fetching it once, storing in the database and query whatever the user needs and display it. The point is I might need to send a request to API some other time in order to fetch newly added data and for this issue I thought either scheduling a certain time where the system fetches the data again from the API or manually send a request to obtain the new data.

To clarify my point, here's how I imagine the sequence:

1. Request for the first time to API to obtain data
2. Save the data in my DB and query what the user needs, thus
   minimizing the time needed to fetch the data and also the number of
   request sent to the server
3. Set automatically/manually a certain time schedule where I would resend
   another request to the API to find if new data has been added

My question: Is my approach doable and efficient or could all of that be done in much more easier way?

**UPDATE:**

I would be using gAdventures API to list different tours along with their details.

1. Max number of tours returned per request is 100.
2. To fetch tour details, tour id returned should have a request sent to fetch all of the details concerning it, so we are talking about thousands of trips. Exact size of data is unavailable till now.

Comment: The data ... how much is it? 2MB? 500MB?

Comment: @MarcoMura kindly check the update in the question

Comment: After update: If the data are > 2MB then i suggest you to use your sequence. Otherwise you can start an animation and wait response.

Comment: @MarcoMura any idea how can I determine the size of the data?!

Comment: Do some fetch and compare the weight (save them into a single file each time) with the tours number :) an avg or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using my Swiss Cache library. It supports file based caching and APC. Even image cache (WIP). If the amount of data is big, my library supports Gzip compression enabled by default. So large amounts of data is automatically compressed.

Example Code of my library:

```
//Your API request function...
require_once("swiss_cache.php");

$cache = new swiss_cache();

$data = $cache->get("gAdventures_response");

if(!$data)
{
     $data = someFunctionThatCallsTheService();
     $cache->set("gAdventures_response", $data, 3600); //Save data for one hour.
}
```

Just make sure you set the cache path in the swiss_cache.php! :) If you have any issues or questions with my library. Just send me a message! The documentation is being worked on.

https://github.com/ajm113/swiss_cache

Comment: Any hints about installation, requirements or pre-requisites concerning your library?!
Your github link is almost empty

Comment: As for right now since I still need to do more further testing and development. The requirements as far as I know is.

(Optional) APC: => 3.0.13,
PHP: => 4.0.1,
(Optional)GD => 1,
(Optional)ImageMagic => 2.0.0

Comment: But if you run into any issues or errors, just let me know your current PHP setup, and I'll add it to the doc.

Comment: Well thats a PHP framework, so that really shouldn't matter in this case and I'm guesting it requires PHP 5 and up. (I haven't used this framework yet) As long as you know where to put the library in the framework so that you can access it. You should be in business.

I did find this article here which should help you get going, encase not.
http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading